# Define type of a property based on another property in the same interface

Tags: typescript, generics, interface

I have a pretty simple interface

```
type MessageType = 'name' | 'age';
type MessageData = string | number 

interface Message {
    type: MessageType;
    data: MessageData;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve now is, when creating an object that implements `Message` with a type of `name`, to let TypeScript know, that `data` must be of type `string` and lint it, if this is not the case.

```
const message: Message = {
    type: 'name',
    data: 'Michael'
}
```

I kind of achieved this with this implementation

```
type MessageType = 'name' | 'age';
type MessageData<T extends MessageType> = T extends 'name' ? string : number;

interface Message<T extends MessageType> {
    type: T;
    data: MessageData<T>;
}

const message: Message<'name'> = {
    type: 'name',
    data: 'Michael'
}
```

However, I don't want to provide `MessageType` and rather have `Message` to use the value I pass in for `type`.

You can play around with this scenario [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzCAVc0C8UDkAdkgLYR5QA++qZA3ALABQoksCyaAIksEgDzooEAB7AIBACbw2iGpkgA+KLkEixk6YRJkoAfijxgAJwCWBFFABcUAgFdiAIwhGGjJmbFGAZkgDG0OFk0ASFRcSkZDgwsJQBvJihEqBYIa3RXJKgJHiRrQKjuXgEFVwBfJiZfAHsCQyhSINTImj4tUjwlXHjGTJTrNrIAGgSk7N5+mBNfAAskCAAbPCZyt0Zq2uAshBMjCAl8mjz2GmUobt6sfqJ24Z7RnImp2YWlxhWgA)

**SOULTION**

Highly scaleable solution found with the help of [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz):

```
interface MessageDataMap {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    gender: 'male' | 'female';
    // ....
}

type MessageType = keyof MessageDataMap;

type Message = {
  [K in MessageType]: {
    type: K;
    data: MessageDataMap[K];
  };
}[MessageType];
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a [mcve]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a type alias instead of an interface for `Message`, since you're naturally talking about a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions), and interfaces can't represent unions.  I'd define it like this:

```
type Message = {
  [K in MessageType]: { type: K; data: MessageData<K> }
}[MessageType];
```

The first part is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) which produces an object like `{name: {type: "name", data: string}, age: {type: "age", data: number}`, and the last part is a [lookup type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) that gets a union of the values of that type... namely `{type: "name", data: string} | {type: "age", data: number}`.  This should then work as you expect:

```
const desiredMessage: Message = {
  type: "name",
  data: "Michael"
};

const alsoDesiredMessage: Message = {
  type: "age",
  data: 14
};

const badMessage: Message = {
  type: "name",
  data: 14
}; // error! number is not string
```

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzCAVc0C8UBEAdkgLYR5QA++qZA3ALABQoksCyaAIksEgDzooEAB7AIBACbw2iGpkgA+KLkEixk6YRJkoAfijxgAJwCWBFFABcUAgFdiAIwhGGjJi2hxZaZVADeTFBQANoA0lBmMhwYWAC61n5QHtahtFASPEjWXtHcvHyhSgC+TEXBOXJxrkwAxgD2BIbpCCZGEBIVaNnsNL4BjEHJ+ESkeAA0gemZ1ngwJjUAFkgQADZ4pdWM9Y3AUEgr8HWcLW0dPV1Rvbj9g1gzNOOTGbzWAIwALBtMtQ1NDkhnbwQbpAvqTIZaUYTAZTF5QD4bKAAeiRQiMRjqRgAhDZ7E4jBFpAQ6rtDKZzEwgA)

Note that your `MessageType` and `MessageData` types represent your constraint somewhat indirectly... the conditional type for `MessageData` probably doesn't scale well if `MessageType` starts growing.  Instead I'd suggest using a helper interface like this:

```
interface MessageDataMap {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
```

Then your `MessageType` and `MessageData` can be represented as `keyof`/lookup types

```
type MessageType = keyof MessageDataMap
type MessageData<T extends MessageType> = MessageDataMap[T]
```

That will behave exactly the same as before but you can add properties to `MessageDataMap` with relative ease.

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIQM4bgcwgETjDlTgAdkBvAWAChkHkQ4BbCALmQzClBwG46jZLg5MAriwBG0QbQC+dOmACeZFOiyiAKmpQBeZAGsIKgPYw0mbHkLFSZZXqtbbROAB5tyCAA9IIAAmGC42ELrqAHzIhpphdiTkANraALpKtKrqoaIxVELISQDSyKA5eBEQqZyUyFliRfzIge6ccaIJHkXRigpJ7RV6qXJ0CGYg3M2YwFAQgQNiC3k09HV6nABEzGwbADQFLcSbqMAIABZwEAA2G3TyI7RjE2AiVxhm+NOz89aibb94ZYFeqbUR7A6tZAARgALHcHk9JlI4D9XIsAQZ8qsQcgtqwIODVoc4JxYfDkAB6Ck+KBQMxQACEEmk0FKIRAZhe3F4IBwdCAA)

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!